# Knockout 2d observable Array not updating

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have Json data as:

```
    "visualAttributes": {
           "stemAppearance": [
                "a",
                "b",
                "c",
                "k",
                "l"
           ],
           "foamAppearance": [
                "yellow",
                "red",
                "green",
                "blue",
                "grey",
           ],
           "adhesionAppearance": [
                "y",
                "y",
                "i",
                "o",
                "o"
           ],
           "stemAngle": [
                "z",
                "x",
                "c",
                "r",
                "v",
              ]
       }
```

which after parsing I use to generate 2d ObservableArray in my view model with the following code:

```
self.visualAttributes = ko.observableArray([]);

self.setVisualAttributes = function(visualAttributes) {
        for(attribute in visualAttributes) {

                var attr = ko.observableArray();
                for(var i=0; i<visualAttributes[attribute].length; i++) {
                     cell = ko.observable(visualAttributes[attribute][i]); 
                     attr.push(cell);

                }
            self.visualAttributes.push(attr);
            }

    }
```

I render it on HTML Table by:

```
    <tbody data-bind="foreach : $root.visualAttributes">

                                <tr>

                                <!-- ko foreach: $data -->
                                    <td><input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value: $data"></input></td>
                                <!-- /ko -->
                                </tr>
                            </tbody>
```

The table renders properly and I am able to see the values. However, on editing any value in the cell, the data does not get updated in the self.visualAttributes() variable. Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Knockout doesn't really handle nested plain observables and `value: $data` very well... It's probably best to make a `Cell` viewmodel that sports a `value` attribute:

```
function Cell(value) { this.value = ko.observable(value); }

// In loop
var cell = new Cell(visualAttributes[attribute][i]);
attr.push(cell);

// In view
<input data-bind="value: value" />
```

There's also this weird work around, which makes sure you bind to an actual reference of the observable, rather than the unwrapped value:

```js
const data = ko.observableArray([
  [ ko.observable("1"), ko.observable("2") ],
  [ ko.observable("a"), ko.observable("b") ]
])

ko.applyBindings({ data });

const unwrwappedData = ko.pureComputed(
  () => data().map(row => row.map(ko.unwrap))
)

unwrwappedData.subscribe(console.log);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tbody data-bind="foreach: data">
    <tr data-bind="foreach: $data">
      <td><input type="text" data-bind="value: $parent[$index()]"></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks.